# How To set up SCP from localhost to remote Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I am trying to configure an ubuntu vps. I have set up ssh secure login using rsa public and private keys from a local machine.

As well as disabling root login I have also set up iptables and configured to allow ports 80 and 22 (port 22 only from my ip address) for the ssh tunnel.

I can connect fine using ssh but when I try using scp from my local machine

```
sudo scp /var/www/filetocopy user@remoteaddress:/var/www/filetocopy
```

I get this error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Does this mean that I have to generate another public key/private key pair or is there a way of using the key that the ssh uses?

many thanks in advance

Comment: When you say you can connect fine using ssh, do you mean using `sudo ssh`?

Comment: yes I mean sudo ssh

Comment: Don't you need to ssh first , and after the tunnel is established, then run the SCP commands?

Comment: @djangofan - No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCP works over SSH so there shouldn't be any additional setup or configuration. Throw a `-v` in there after `scp` and let's get some more information.

That said, it looks like the SCP command isn't passing the key you generated.  Try specifying the key file with the `-i` option.  If it is in a non-standard location or non-standard name you'll need to let it know what to use rather than the default ~/.ssh/id_rsa.

Comment: tried to display the whole log but it's too long but basically the keys match and a connection is made but it says this `debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey`

Comment: That's fine, only the last few lines should be relevant to the failure. That's saying the receiving side will only accept publickey and it fails as none is sent. Did you try the `-i` option with your key? That should do the trick. Are you using ssh-agent? Or do you have to specify your keys passphrase each time you SSH?

Comment: Have you had any luck sorting this out?